# Cannot write a subset of features back to the source Geopackage or File Geodatabase

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, select, geopackage, subset

At QGIS 2.18.16, I have a Geopackage point layer with a selection subset.  I need to write the selected records to the same Geopackage as a new layer, with a new name.

When I attempt to **Save As...** the new layer, QGIS responds with this error:

[image]

It appears that QGIS thinks that I'm trying to ***overwrite*** the original layer, when I'm actually trying to create a ***new*** layer that is a subset of the original.

Interestingly, the same error occurs if I attempt the same with a File Geodatabase; that is, I try to write a subset of records as a new Feature Class to the original FGDB.

[A Google search turned up the same error](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16588), but in that case the user was trying to overwrite the source layer.

I expect that QGIS should be able to write a subset of a layer's records to the source Geopackage or File Geodatabase under a new name.  How can I accomplish this without the error?

As a workaround, I can write the subset to a different Geopackage (or FGDB), and then copy that to the original Geopackage (or FGDB).

Comment: seems pedantic, but...I'm missing a question mark? ,) however, I woudn't know if this is expected behaviour or maybe a bug even...

Comment: Fair enough, OP edited to include a specific question.

Comment: I made a successful trial with QGIS 3.0.1.

Comment: @user30184 I was excited to see your success at 3.0.1, so I tried it at 3.0.2 (Windows 7, 64-bit OSGEO install) and still have the same error.  In my OP (now updated) I forgot to mention that I was using Save As...  Is this how you are successfully saving your subset selection, or some other technique?

Answer (score 1):

I had success with QGIS 3.0.1 this way:

- Open a layer from .gpkg database
- Select some features
- Edit - Copy Features
- Edit - Paste Features as.. New Vector Layer

Use an existing .gpkg as a target file but give a new name for the target layer

[image]

The new layer is created into the existing GeoPackage

[image]

Comment: Worked in version 3.0.2 (Linux)