# Saving duplicate geometry layers into a geopackage?

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I have a bunch of variables to map with same geometry (Regional Boundaries), and wanted to create separate layers with differing attributes within a single geopackage file for ease of file management. However, when I save the duplicate layer into a geopackage I get an error "Export to vector file failed. Error: Cannot overwrite a OGR layer in place". This seems to be expected behavior according to [this bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16588). Is there a way around this? Creating separate gpkg files for each layer seems to be unnecessary/superfluous. Or am I misunderstanding the entire concept of geopackage as a an analogue to Esri's geodatabase?

Comment: Do your layers have different names?

Comment: yes. Names are different. Otherwise they are identical (same geometry/attributes).

Comment: GeoPackage does not set such limitations. Perhaps QGIS does. With ogr2ogr it is for sure possible.

Comment: the bug report doesn't say it's expected, just that it looks that way to the program. reopen the bug report and make it clearer why this is an issue

Comment: According to this post, the problem has been solved with QGIS 3:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281201/cannot-write-a-subset-of-features-back-to-the-source-geopackage-or-file-geodatab

Comment: Not sure if you can count that as a solution, seems more like a workaround a bug. Will have to test it later.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I should have used the term "workaround" instead of "solution".

Comment: I consider also that https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16588 is a bug and it should be reopened. When it comes to the answer to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281201/cannot-write-a-subset-of-features-back-to-the-source-geopackage-or-file-geodatab I do not think it is was a workaround with the context of the question but it could be used as a workaround for your problem.

Comment: I will re-open it once I will try the workaround and can formulate my issue a bit more concisely/precisely. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicated layer in QGIS seems not to be self-standing copy of the data but rather a shadow of the original layer. If you edit the shadow layer and save the edits the original layer is edited by the same. Or in other words, you can't really edit the shadow but you edit the real object behind it. I suppose that the reason of having duplicated layers is to make it possible to have different renderings from the same data. But they look like normal layers in user interface which is confusing.

Comment: So is that not a bug, but a feature of gpkg then? I'm just not sure whether the issue is my misinterpretation of gpkg, or that the gpkg should work in a different way and it is a bug?

Comment: This has nothing to do with GeoPackage. You can save however many tables you want into GeoPackage. The trouble you have is special for QGIS and especially the "duplicate layer" feature that you are using. Change your workflow and don't duplicate your layers. And the Import vector layer method in my answer works, haven't you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @user30184 for an answer, that prompted me to discover a workflow that works even better for me. Since my original question was nested in need to create multiple thematic layers (primarily based on excel sheets + attribute joins), I discovered that doing a join on a layer and then saving it into the geopackage does not prompt any errors. So instead of duplicating layers and then attaching attributes through table joins, it is easier to do joins first and save files after (as output from the join), then there are no errors and duplicate geometries are saved into a single GPKG.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Save as... option use the DB Manager tool.
In the example below I had opened layer "test_2" from GeoPackage "test" and I imported it back to the same GeoPackage with a new name. I tested that is is possible to import duplicated layers in the same manner.

[image]

Comment: Which QGIS version did you use?

Comment: Version seems to be 3.0.3.