# Multiple attribute layers with same geometry in geopackage with ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr, attribute-joins, geopackage

I have multiple PostGIS tables I want to export to a single gpkg file. The tables have identical schema, and identical geometries -- the numerical attributes differ. How do I create a gpkg file, using ogr2ogr with these multiple tables, without duplicating the identical geometries? I need to use ogr2ogr because this needs to be scripted.

My question is related to this existing question [Saving duplicate geometry layers into a geopackage?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284951/saving-duplicate-geometry-layers-into-a-geopackage) but I don't see a solution using ogr2ogr.

I am using the `-update` flag per the accepted answer here: [Saving duplicate geometry layers into a geopackage?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284951/saving-duplicate-geometry-layers-into-a-geopackage)

Is there a way to tell ogr2ogr / gpkg to not duplicate the geometries? Or are the only solutions to either have all attributes in a single feature table (many many columns), or have 1 feature table and many attribute tables, and then perform joins in an application when opening the gpkg?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to this :-(